# Callback function issue in flutter

Tags: function, flutter, dart, callback, parameter-passing

I have two callback functions in a stateful widget which are called by two different screens. Here is the how I declared them in the stateful widget(onChange and finalBetList);

```
class AppListView extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueChanged onChange;
  final List<MatchList> matchList;
  final ValueChanged finalBetList;

  AppListView({this.onChange, this.matchList, this.finalBetList});
```

And this is how I implemented them in the state class of the widget. Even if I try to pass the same parameter onChange working perfectly but finalBetList getting this error. 
The method 'call' was called on null.Receiver: null Tried calling: call(1)

```
widget.onChange(counter);
widget.finalBetList(counter);
```

Everything is same, one of them is workiing but other one get the error. What I'm missing?

Edit

This is the code where I call my stateful widget from HomeScreen(which works perfect)

```
          Stack(children: [
              AppListView(
                matchList: matchList,
                //callback function brings the counter value from ListView class
                onChange: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    counter = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
```

This is the code where I call my stateful widget from second secreen(which gets error)

```
body: Container(
        child: AppListView(
            onChange: (value) {},
            finalBetList: (value) {
              counter = value;
              setState(() {
                //counter = value;
              });
            },
            matchList: matchList),
      ),
```

Comment: Provide the code where you instantiate a AppListView

Comment: I added the code to the end of the question

Comment: Are you sure that the first code snippet is the one that runs perfectly? Because there you don't specify the finalBetList, which leaves it as null

Comment: onChange works perfectly, finalBetList got error. What is the difference?

Comment: What you mean as saying you dont specify finalBetList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Assign an empty body implemention to the `finalBetList` property

```
Stack(children: [
              AppListView(
                matchList: matchList,
                finalBetList: (value) {}, // <- NEW CODE IS HERE
                //callback function brings the counter value from ListView class
                onChange: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    counter = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
```

---

**Why should you do it?**

In Dart, functions are objects. Objects, if not assigned a value, are `null`. In the code example from `HomeScreen` you assign a value to `onChange`, so later when you call it through `widget.onChange(counter)`, `onChange` is evaluated as a function object and its body is executed.

However, in the same example you don't assign any value to `finalBetList` so it's left as `null`. When you make the call `widget.finalBetList(counter)`, `finalBetList` is evaluated and it's clearly not a function object. At this point you'd except an error, but it's not the end of the story - as not only function objects can be called. Any class that implements the `call()` method can be called, too. So a call to `finalBetList.call()` is attempted. This is the exception you should get:

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'call' was called on null.
Receiver: null
```

Obviously `null` doesn't implement a `call()` method so it doesn't exists and an exception is thrown.

If you don't want to assign an empty body implemention to the `finalBetList` property inside `HomeScreen`, you also have the option to assign it in the constructor.

Another option I can think of is calling the function using conditional member access:

```
widget.finalBetList?.call(counter);
```

All function objects have the `call()` method which executes the function's body.